# bash: can't read /dev/stdin when running as another user

Tags: bash

For debugging, I want to replace executable `foo`, which is normally run by user `vmail`, to log the arguments and standard input. This is part of the replacement script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
  echo "$line" >> logfile
done < /dev/stdin
```

This fails. So, to test it, I run it as:

```
# su -s /bin/bash vmail
$ ./foo
```

This also fails, with `/dev/stdin: Permission denied`, because `/dev/stdin` is still owned (and only readable) by me in the new shell. Any suggestions for a fix? I can't simply use `cat` because of an 'ambiguous redirect' error. Thanks.

Comment: I am confused; it seems like redirecting input from `/dev/stdin` is  no-op: you're *already* reading from *stdin*, even without that redirect.

Comment: @larsks: I cut it down from `${1:-/dev/stdin}` (to allow a filename parameter) without realising it turned into a no-op. Interestingly, it *does* work without `< /dev/stdin`, but fails with it. So, just taking it out is an answer, but still confused.

Comment: try with `sudo login <username>` and execute your script.